# SmothStop Function doesn't work as expected

Tags: unity, mathematics, curves

i'm trying to create a smothstop function i need it to control time variable on my lerp function used to move character and so on...what i have is this

```
    private float SmothStop(float t)
{
    return  1 - (1 - t * t * t * t * t);

}
```

problem here is that will start slow then accelerate... same as smothstart function.. that i already tested and work on that way.. so.. what i'm missing up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look what happens when we multiply through the parentheses here:

```
  1 - (1 - t * t * t * t * t)
= 1 - 1 + t * t * t * t * t
= t * t * t * t * t
```

So you just re-wrote SmoothStart in disguise.

It looks like what you want is:

```
float s = 1f - t;

return 1 - s * s * s * s * s;
```

When t is close to 1, s is close to zero. Raising to the 5th power creates a shallow slope around `s = 0` (`t = 1`), and a steep slope around `s = 1` (`t = 0`). Subtracting from 1 ensures the function is still increasing from 0 to 1 as t increases from 0 to 1.

Comment: Thank’s uou really so much! I got the pont!